# how to add middleware that converts response from one class to different class

Tags: spring

Lets say I have controller that look like this:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
  @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public Response hello {
    return new Response("hello");
  }
}
```

And the Response class look like this:

```
public class Response {
  public String text;

  public Response(String text) {
    this.text = text;
  }
}
```

So now if anyone call /test he gets

```
{
  "text": "hello"
}
```

This `Response` shared across all my controllers.

So now I want somehow to convert this `Response` into `ResponseEntity<Response>` and manipulate it before it's send into the client in one place.

I thought about Interceptor but I found this note:

> Note that postHandle is less useful with @ResponseBody and ResponseEntity methods for which the response is written and committed within the HandlerAdapter and before postHandle. That means it is too late to make any changes to the response, such as adding an extra header. For such scenarios, you can implement ResponseBodyAdvice and either declare it as an Controller Advice bean or configure it directly on RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.

[source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor)

But I can't make `ResponseBodyAdvice` to convert the response class type.

Comment: What do you need to change.

Comment: @M.Deinum I want to add response ID in the response headers, or the HTTP status code.

Comment: You can do that directly in the controller, the headres can be set on the `ResponseEntity`directly. Which is why you would use this in the first place. If you need another ID, just use a filter or interceptor and in the `preHandle` set the header instead of the `postHandler`.

Comment: @M.Deinum What if I need to change it according to the Response class?

Comment: Then why not do it in the controller self, you have all the information in there.

Comment: @M.Deinum because I have same logic in multiple controllers

Comment: Then create a factory that creates the `ResponseEntity` based on your `Result` object. You can generify it else an interceptor/advice wouldn't help either.